# Modify javascript that was downloaded as part of a web page

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to modify the Javascript that is downloaded as part of a web page.

I have this page:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7629335

I would like to modify the function jspaginate.init.  I've gotten this far:

```
console.log(window.jspaginate)
Object { data: Object, loading: false, init: jspaginate.init(), update: jspaginate.update(), pushState: jspaginate.pushState(), loadingSequence: jspaginate.loadingSequence(), removeLoading: jspaginate.removeLoading(), updateUI: jspaginate.updateUI(), getData: jspaginate.getData() }
undefined

console.log(window.jspaginate["init"])
function jspaginate.init()
console.log(window.jspaginate["init"].toString())
function (action, last){
    var view = this,
        target, current;
... clipped ...
```

background: 
This page includes lots of javascript. The function jspaginate is download from the site server. Nevertheless, I need to change the function jspaginate. I do not have access to the server. I want to change my copy of jspaginate. I know that I need to change the function every time it is downloaded.

I'm using GreaseMonkey to insert some javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the init function with its new definition, like below:

```
window.jspaginate.init = function() { 
   console.log('there you go');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code I used.  Since I had converted jspaginate.init to a string and modified the string, I had to convert the string to a function.  I did the conversion via the eval function.

```
var debug = 1;
/* Get the string of the function to change */
var stringed = jspaginate["init"].toString();
  if ( debug ) console.log ("--> cloneGotoChange: \n" + stringed); 

/* Place the added code as the last statement in the function jspaginate["init"]      
   Find the function closing } */
position = stringed.lastIndexOf("}");

/* Change the downloaded javascript */
var newCode = stringed.substr(0, position)
    + " console.log (\"-->  before \" );  cloneGotoUpate(); console.log (\"-->  after \" ); " 
    + stringed.substr(position);

/* Inject the changed code 
   need to use the eval function to make a function assignment instead of a string assignment */
eval( 'jspaginate["init"] =' + newCode);
  if ( debug ) console.log (console.log(window.jspaginate["init"].toString()));
```